# Random Color generation with one RGB set to 255

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to get a random color for my background. Only one thing, one of the value should be 255. Like (234,85,38) is not fine, but (33,255,82) is fine.

Currently I'm trying to first switch a random for which value (R,G or B) should be 255. Then in each case I'm defining the other values at random. But it doesn't work.

```
void setBackgroundColor(){
        Color color = new Color();
        switch(Random.Range(1,3)){
            case 1:
                color = new Color(255, Random.Range(1,255), Random.Range(1,255));
                break;
            case 2:
                color = new Color(Random.Range(1,255), 255, Random.Range(1,255));
                break;
            case 3:
                color = new Color(Random.Range(1,255), Random.Range(1,255), 255);
                break;
        }
        Camera.main.backgroundColor = color;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing! Oh... wait, were you having a problem somewhere...? No? Great! ;-P

Comment: What is the question you want to ask?

Comment: @elgonzo yeah i need to edit it. It doesn't work, basically.

Comment: @Sweeper It doesn't work

Comment: Keep in mind `Random.Range` with integers is not maximally inclusive. So you will never get 3 in switch.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, couple of issues. The first is that the `Color` class uses float values from 0 to 1 to represent its colors. If you're looking explicitly to set values based on the 0-255 scale, you want the `Color32` class. That said, `Color` probably serves you fine and has more features to boot, you just need to remember that you want to use the *float* version of `Random.Range()`, rather than the integer version. Specifying the parameters as floats fixes that:

```cs
void setBackgroundColor(){
    Color color = new Color();
    switch(Random.Range(1,3)){
        case 1:
            color = new Color(1f, Random.Range(0f ,1f), Random.Range(0f, 1f));
            break;
        case 2:
            color = new Color(Random.Range(0f, 1f), 1f, Random.Range(0f, 1f));
            break;
        case 3:
            color = new Color(Random.Range(0f, 1f), Random.Range(0f, 1f), 1f);
            break;
    }
    Camera.main.backgroundColor = color;
}
```

Now, we can actually compress this further. Something to remember is that you can access the RGBA components of a color using `color[0]` through `color[3]`. In that, you can actually simplify your code to just generate a random color and then overwrite a random index:

```cs
void setBackgroundColor() {
    Color color = new Color(Random.Range(0f, 1f), Random.Range(0f ,1f), Random.Range(0f, 1f));
    color[Random.Range(0,2)] = 1f;
    Camera.main.backgroundColor = color;
}
```

Now this is better, but thinking on what you're trying to do, I'm going to hazard a guess and say you want a color that's not too dark or desaturated. Consider explicitly generating a color from HSV (Hue, Saturation, Value) values using the `Color.HSVToRGB()` function:

```cs
void setBackgroundColor() {
    Camera.main.backgroundColor = Color.HSVToRGB(Random.Range(0f, 1f), 1f, 1f);
}
```

With this, we just specify that it's the *hue* of the color we want to randomize, rather than anything else. And in fact, there's one more optimization: This is a one line function, and it probably only gets called in one place. You can likely just delete the function call entirely and replace it with the contents of the function:

```cs
Camera.main.backgroundColor = Color.HSVToRGB(Random.Range(0f, 1f), 1f, 1f);
```

**EDIT:**
You know what? There's an even cleaner way to do this. Because it turns out, `Random` has a function called `Random.ColorHSV()`:

```cs
Camera.main.backgroundColor = Random.ColorHSV(0f, 1f, 1f, 1f, 1f, 1f);
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I just understood how dumb my question really was. You just turned a 11 line of code to a single line. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Is there any way I can ignore a certain range of colors? My player is red in color, so i want my background not to be red. How can i achieve that?

Comment: Well, hue is red at high and low values, so you could just change the first two parameters to be something like 0.2f and 0.8f. Alternatively, you could set the middle two values to 0.5f so you always get desaturated colors upon which other brightly colored objects stand out. But maybe now is the time to choose a particular color for your background? This is the burden of the designer: making tough choices!